# WMV files do not play in Totem

Tags: 14.04, totem, wmv

Trying to play any .wmv file in Totem gives the following error:

> (totem:2491): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_new_empty:
>   assertion 'gst_structure_validate_name (name)' failed Segmentation
>   fault (core dumped)

Restricted extras are installed, and I've also tried removing any .gstreamer config files from my home directory. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use Totem? You can install **VLC player** from Ubuntu repositories and also **xine** together with **xine-ui** (**sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc** and if you want to **sudo apt-get install xine xine-ui gxine**) and you can play almost any video file format with either of these 2 LITE video players. Totem is heavy package dude!

Comment: I prefer its simple interface. VLC also doesn't play .wmv's for me anyway.

Comment: If it's a simple interface that you need then I suggest you install Gstreamer 1.0 from the [developers page](https://launchpad.net/~gstreamer-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty). Run sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0* after adding the ppa to your software sources list. The command for launching Gstreamer 1.0 is present in **/usr/bin/gst-play-1.0**. When opening a video file, choose Open With and select **/usr/bin/gst-play-1.0**. It goes fullscreen, you can pause it, and it will play your wmv files.

Comment: I am not sure that **Open With** was a wise suggestion for opening local video files with Gstreamer 1.0. It works best in a terminal window where you can use a code like **gst-play-1.0 [path to the file]**