# WMV files crash VLC and totem

Tags: vlc, crash, totem

please don't consider my question a dublicated as searched  this website for every single solution but no use ! WMV files crash VLC and totem but smplayer works fine please help !
here is some answers I tried
[WMV files do not play in Totem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534747/wmv-files-do-not-play-in-totem?rq=1)

[VLC unable to play wmv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568987/vlc-unable-to-play-wmv?rq=1)

I tried reinstalling ubuntu restriected extras , ffmpeg and vlc but still having the same problem every time I try to open wmv file a program window appears for less than second and dissappears . I recently updated VLC to so I tried downgrading I also tried to run wmv file form terminal using vlc I have "Segmentation fault"

Comment: All right. I don't consider your question a duplicate. But... can you elaborate what you are experiencing, what is the problem, how it manifests and what have you tried to deal with it? Along with links to other questions that had answers that didn't work for you? Along with what went wrong when you tried these answers?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/595062/ubuntu-mate-14-04-blinking-wifi-light-hp-g60 this question for some advice how to ask a question when you fear it might be closed as a duplicate.